# RuntimeError: cannot open "feature class" with SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, runtimeerror

I have a very simple script that isn't working.

```
import arcpy

workspace = "C:\\Users\\Work\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.3\\ArcCatalog\\master.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

wire = "gis.DBO.wire"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(wire, "id") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0]
```

It returns `RuntimeError: cannot open 'gis.DBO.wire'`

---

**UPDATED**

I still haven't figured this out. I just did a repair on ArcGIS Desktop 10.3, and that didn't solve it. So, then I removed Python, and reinstalled it and it still doesn't work.

I have this script I've tried running in PyScripter and IDLE:

```
import arcpy
sde = "C:\\Temp\\Data.sde"
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(sde)
```

I get:

[image]

And, yes it is a valid sde connection.

**If I do the exact same code above in the Python window of ArcCatalog it works fine.**

Here's the IDLE error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(sde)
RuntimeError
```

Comment: If you just call arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(), does it list gis.DBO.wire? "True" might be spurious in this case... And, do you have read/write access to that directory?

Comment: Do you get this error message when calling your connection via Database connections: `workspace = r"Database Connections\master.sde"`?

Comment: I am suffering this issue in a random way: I have 3 scripts, each of them create the sde(same username, password and database) file, then use it for collecting some info from a table(same table). These scripts run every night, and from time to time, one of  the scripts fail with this error. I used the verification for the table as mentioned by @GeostoneMarten (arcpy.Exist) but now the point of failure is the verification, not the search cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are treating the SearchCursor() like a geo-processing tool. Geo-processing tools can honour 1 or more environment settings (which you find out by looking at the help for the tool) and one such setting is workspace.

Nowhere on the help page for [SearchCursor()](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) does it state that *Workspace* is an environment setting that it honours. In fact I don't think it honours any! So you need to provide the full path because currently you are providing a string `"gis.DBO.wire"`.

Comment: `SearchCursor` definitely does honor the set workspace because I use it fine on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. I think it works. I haven't sde connection. I can't test

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env  
env.overwriteOutput = True  

env.workspace ="Database Connections/master.sde"

# check name
fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()    

for fcname in fc_list:  
    print fc  

#if wire is named gis.DBO.wire
# use in cursor full name
fcname = "gis.DBO.wire"
fc = os.path.join(env.workspace,fcname)

# check if exist
if arcpy.Exists(fc):
   print "Featureclass Exist"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "id") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0]
```